# Serialize jackson class so fields are treated as unamed elements of parent array

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a json format I'm trying to create a jackson model object for.  The JSON format is predefined.  Part of the format looks like this:

```
entities: [
    {
      id: "",
      name: "",
      type: "",
      ...
     }
    {
      id: "",
      name: "",
      type: "",
      ...
     }
    (etc etc)
    ]
```

Each of these 'entity' objects may have different fields.  For instance I may have a user entity, an account entity, and a provider entity etc.  The JSON is generic, but in my case I'm building to a specific template and I know the type of every entity I will be creating.  I could do something like this and it would work:

```
 public class MyTemplate{

     public Entity[] entities;

     public MyTemplate(){
         entities=new Entity[NUM_ENTITIES];
         entities[ENTITY_LOC.User]=new UserEntity();
         entities[ENTITY_LOC.Account]=new AccountEntity();
     }

     public void setUser(UserEntity user){
         entities[ENTITY_LOC.User]=user;
     }
 }
```

This would searlize correctly, and be a horribly ugly model object.  What I would prefer would be to have something like this:

```
  Public Class MyTemplate{

      UserEntity user;
      AccountEntity account;

      public MyTemplate(){
          user=new UserEntity();
          account=new AccountEntity();
      }

      public void setUser(UserEntity user){
           this.user=user;
      }
  }
```

The question is how do I make the above object serialize to fit the expected JSON format, as if each of the named field was nothing more then a generic object in a Collection named entities?  I know I can overwrite the serialization parser, but is there a way to do this simply with annotations?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without writing a custom deserializer. In your example, how would Jackson know what type each `Entity` mapped to? By checking the `type` field?

Comment: It took me a second to realize you said *de*serialize, but yes your right.  I don't see any way of avoiding custom deserialization.  Any chance that at least serialization can be done automagically? :)

Comment: Oh sorry, that's my fault for missing that point in your question. Let me know if my answer helps.

Comment: @shawnb no you didn't miss the point of the question, I hadn't realized the deserilization issue and it is a good point.  I was just thrown off for a second because I presumed you said serialize and was going to argue that your comment made no sense until I reread it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to serialize from the `MyTemplate` structure in your second code example to the JSON you provided, unless you also write a custom serializer. However, if you're fine with `MyTemplate` using a `List` of `Entities` instead:

```
public class MyTemplate {
   List<Entity> entities;

   // accessor, mutator
}
```

Then that will serialize to the JSON in your question just fine. You'll still need to write a custom deserializer, and you'll need your `User` and `Account` models to extend `Entity`, and then put whatever fields or logic will be necessary for determining the type of your entities in that parent class.

The heavy lifting will be in your custom deserializer.

`Entity` class:

```
public class Entity {
   private String id;       
   private String type;
   private String name;

   // accessors, mutators
}
```

`UserEntity` class:

```
public class UserEntity extends Entity {
   // UserEntity specific fields, logic
}
```